# How to find where my Disk Space has gone

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, disk-space-utilization

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2. I have 500GB from 2 SSD drives. I currently have 7GB disk space. I have ran CCleaner but there was no change.

I keep only the main files on the disks and I had a good 50GB of disk space free awhile ago.

Is there a way I can run powershell or figure out where my space is being used like you can in Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest approach is probably to check with a graphical utility like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/).

Comment: WinDirStat is great, +1!

Answer (score 4):

If your not running core, [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/) is my fav.

But if your looking for Linux's `du` like results in powershell:

`gci . | %{$f=$_; gci -r $_.FullName | measure-object -property length -sum | select  @{Name="Name"; Expression={$f}} , @{Name="Sum (MB)"; Expression={  "{0:N3}" -f ($_.sum / 1MB) }}, Sum } | sort Sum -desc | format-table -Property Name,"Sum (MB)", Sum -autosize`

It's From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824039/611497) I remember using it ages ago, certainly slower and not as powerful as `du`. But it is a one liner.